# Population count between two positions

Tags: c, performance, algorithm, bit-manipulation, bioinformatics

I am looking for a solution of finding pop count in bitstring between two positions
eg:

```
popcnt( 10(0101), 0, 3) = 1
popcnt( 100101(), 0, 0) = 0
popcnt( 10010(1), 0, 1) = 0
```

** I am assuming open range and assuming Right to Left order

using standard bit operators and possibly popcnt or equivalent.

If it makes difference, I am looking to find the popcnt between the difference of two strings.  Lets say i have string `b` and i swap bits in two positions, eg `0101110 -> 1101100 => 3` - I need the popcnt *between* the bits that changed - in the case of `0101110 -> 1101100` the bits between the two are `10110` and so popcnt is 3

Do you see some ingenious way to do so with bithacks?

Comment: Not sure I'm reading this right. XOR the strings and count the numbers of bits set in the result ?

Comment: @cnicutar that tells you difference pocnt, not popcnt between difference

Comment: Check this [link](http://bits.stephan-brumme.com/countBits.html).

Comment: @iccthedral I'm currently confused by that too.@Anycom Are the binary strings to be read from R to L or L to R?

Comment: @iccthedral there are no bits between 0 and 1, so it should be 0

Comment: If there are no bits between 0 and 1, how is (0, 0) different from (0, 1) ?

Comment: @cnicutar they aren't, such is the requirement of the domain

Comment: @Anycom Can you make bold the digits that are being counted in your three examples? I'm currently bamboozled.

Comment: @Anycorn, what do you mean exactly by "possibly popcnt or equivalent"? Are you looking for an opcode?

Comment: How is 0101110 -> 1101100 => 3? You only change 2 bits?

Comment: @Gille The number of bits between the two changed

Comment: @Anycorn thanks for the clarification, now I see. You can just AND them together (&) and then use the answer below.

Comment: What do you mean by "pop count"? The meaning I know (and assumed in my answer) is "number of `1` bits", but this contradicts the examples after you edited the question.

Comment: @interjay sorry, i have made few typos, been staring at screen too long.  the ansdwer you gave me is what works for me.

Comment: Please, correct your examples and explain role of parameters... for( bitrank=2nd-param,bitrank<3rd-param) or 3rd-param is length?

Comment: Also correct 0101110 -> 1101100 => 3, and explain what is 3. After Gill comment, I still do not understand. You changed bit of rank 2 and bit of rank 7, so there are only 4 bits that did not change from rank 3 to 6 inclusive, that is string 1011. You seem to include bit of rank 2 and exclude bit of rank 7 and consider the popcount of string AFTER change 10110, that's very confusing, is it really your intention?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First mask the value to get only the relevant bits:

```
relevant = (value >> startBit) & ((1 << numOfBits) - 1);
```

---

**Edit:**

The above will invoke undefined behavior when `numOfBits == 32` (or more accurately, when `numOfBits == CHAR_BIT * sizeof(int)`). To fix this you need to have special handling for that case (set `relevant = value`).

---

Then find the population count of those bits using one of the methods proposed in this question: [Best algorithm to count the number of set bits in a 32-bit integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/109023/best-algorithm-to-count-the-number-of-set-bits-in-a-32-bit-integer).

To summarize the answers, You can use a platform-specific function such as GCC's `__builtin_popcount`, or if you need a portable solution you can use a parallel-prefix algorithm such as the one from Matt Howells's answer:

```
int NumberOfSetBits(int i)
{
    i = i - ((i >> 1) & 0x55555555);
    i = (i & 0x33333333) + ((i >> 2) & 0x33333333);
    return (((i + (i >> 4)) & 0x0F0F0F0F) * 0x01010101) >> 24;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I am trying to understand the logic now

Comment: It's just a matter of style, but I usually like this form: 
    relevant = (value >> startBit) &~ (-1 << numOfBits)

Comment: What happens when you want 32 bits popcount(x,0,32) ? Does ((1 << numOfBits) - 1); works ?

Comment: @aka.nice: That's indeed an issue: According to the C standard it would be undefined behavior, though I believe that on x86 processor it should give the correct result. I'll replace it with a portable version.

Comment: Actually it gives the wrong result on x86, so the fix will still be needed.

Comment: Instead of masking, you could also do a 2nd shift to knock bits off the high side of the value.  (popcnt doesn't care where the bits are).  Shift right by `startBit`, then shift left by `32-numOfBits`.  (where 32 is actually derived from `CHAR_BIT`).  This only has undefined behaviour when `numOfBits` is zero.